# Автозапуск команд в интервале в несколько секунд Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, автозапуск

В `Ubuntu 16.04` мне надо запустить 4 команды автоматический при запуске системы в интервале несколько секунд каждая, чтобы предыдущая команда успела запуститься.
Делал в `/etc/rc.local` но не работает. А если делать все вручную все работает.

Вот команды:

> sudo systemctl start mongodb
>
> cd /opt/parse-server-example
>
> sudo screen npm start
>
> sudo screen parse-dashboard --config config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1

Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

PS. GUI нету

Comment: Добавьте `sleep 1` после каждой команды.

Comment: не помогло ((((

Comment: А если указать полные пути ко всем файлам и программам?

Comment: сделал так `sudo systemctl start mongodb
sleep 3
sudo node /opt/parse-server-example/index.js` последняя команда никак не хочет выполняться его я убрал, придется вручную делать

Comment: `command1 && command2 && ...` не помогает? По хорошему вам надо вызывать `waitpid()` на каждый запущенный в фоне процесс. На shell это делается не очень сложно, но и не очень просто.

Comment: ключевая фраза "чтобы предыдущая команда успела запуститься" - это базовая функциональность systemd. Нужно просто почитать документацию. И никаких слипов.

Comment: KoVadim прав, это типичная ["ошибка молотка"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Надо не ждать отфонарное количество времени, а дожидаться именно старта сервиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй эту команду в том же /etc/rc.local или засунь в .sh скрипт и положи в крон по событию `@reboot`

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb && sleep 5 \
cd /opt/parse-server-example && sleep 5 \
sudo screen npm start && sleep 5 \
sudo screen parse-dashboard --config config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1 && sleep 5 \
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаем юнит systemd(файл вида [имя юнита].service в директории /etc/systemd/system/) со следующим содержанием:

```
[Unit]
Description=[описание юнита]
Requires=mongodb.service
After=mongodb.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=[полный путь до скрипта server-starter.sh]
PIDFile=[путь до PID фалйа, чтоб systemd мог отслеживать состояние юнита, допустим, /tmp/server-starter.pid]

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

//если надо, можно указать от какого пользователя запускать скрипт(читать документацию к systemd)
//также можно указать директорию из которой будет запускаться скрипт(чтобы убрать строку `cd ...` из скрипта) - тоже читать документацию

Затем создаем скрипт server-starter.sh, содержимое:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/parse-server-example
screen npm start && sleep 5
screen parse-dashboard --config config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1
```

Делаем его исполняемым (`chmod +x server-starter.sh`)

Затем добавляем mongodb и наш юнит в автозапуск:

```
systemctl enable mongodb
systemctl enable [имя юнита]
```

Теперь скрипт будет запускаться строго после запуска mongodb почти без костылей с интервалами. Повторите аналогичные действия для npm start(сделать юнит для него и после запуска этого юнита запускать `screen parse-dashboard...`)

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo -e "1";
    sleep 2&&
    echo -e "2==";
    sleep 2&&
    echo -e "eee"
```

но проще написать для /etc/init.d скрипт
и запускать уже в нем.